# Find solutions of equation involving Bessel functions

Tags: plotting, special-functions, equation-solving

I'm new in Mathematica and I'm trying to find the solutions of this equation involving Bessel functions

$$\eta  \frac{ J_{n+1}(\eta  a)}{J_n(\eta  a)}+\chi \frac{ I_{n+1}(\chi  a)}{I_n(\chi  a)}=0$$

where,

$$ \eta =\sqrt{\frac{\beta ^2 \left(\sqrt{\frac{4 \alpha ^2 \omega ^2}{\beta ^2}+1}-1\right)}{2 \alpha ^2}} \,\,\,,\,\,\,\,\,\chi =\sqrt{\frac{\beta ^2 \left(\sqrt{\frac{4 \alpha ^2 \omega ^2}{\beta ^2}+1}+1\right)}{2 \alpha ^2}}$$

and

$$ \alpha =\sqrt{\frac{h^2 M}{12 \left(1-\nu ^2\right) \rho }} \,\,,\,\,\, \beta =\sqrt{\frac{M T}{\left(1-\nu ^2\right) \rho }}$$

So at the end, my equation is a function of n (which is an integer), $\omega$, h and T.

I need to find the values of $\omega$ or eigenfrequencies for which the equation is satisfied.

Based on this post [Trying to solve a transcendental equation involving Bessel functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/44357/trying-to-solve-a-transcendental-equation-involving-bessel-functions), I tried the following:

```
f[n_, ω_, h_,T_] := η*BesselJ[n+1,η*a]/BesselJ[n,η*a] 
                           + χ*BesselI[n+1, χ*a]/BesselI[n,χ*a]
```

and

```
Manipulate[Plot[f[n_, ω_, h_, T_], {ω, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> {-1000, 1000}], 
                                    {n, 0, 5, 1}, {h, 0.1, 1}, {T, -1, 1}]
```

but the plot does not show anything. (I set a=1)

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the help of Bill's edits, the code should look like this:

```
Clear[f, omega, alpha, beta, h, M, T, v, rho];
eta = 
 Sqrt[beta^2 (Sqrt[4 alpha^2 omega^2/beta^2 + 1] - 1)/(2 alpha^2)]; 
chi = 
 Sqrt[beta^2 (Sqrt[4 alpha^2 omega^2/beta^2 + 1] + 
      1)/(2 alpha^2)]; 
alpha = 
 Sqrt[h^2 M/(12 (1 - v^2) rho)]; 
beta = Sqrt[M T/((1 - v^2) rho)]; 
a = 1;

f[n_, omega_, h_, T_] = 
  eta*BesselJ[n + 1, eta*a]/BesselJ[n, eta*a] + 
   chi*BesselI[n + 1, chi*a]/BesselI[n, chi*a];

Manipulate[
 Plot[f[n, ω, h, T], {ω, 0, 10}, 
  PlotRange -> {-1000, 1000}], {n, 0, 5, 1}, {h, 0.1, 1}, {T, -1, 1}]
```

[image: plot manipulate]

The main missing ingredient is that you defined the parameters `eta` and `chi` outside of the function `f`, but these parameters actually depend on variables that are supposed to be fed into the function (`omega` and the things entering `alpha`, `beta`). To make sure that these outside definitions are incorporated into the definition of `f`, you can replace `SetDelayed` by `Set` (making sure that the necessary variables are cleared. So you just replace the `f[...] := ...` by `f[...] = ...`.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is very helpful!